# How to use postgresql copy command with ANSI encoding?

Tags: postgresql, csv, ansi

I use PostgreSQL copy command to make a csv file.

```
COPY (select * from table) from '/tmp/123456.csv' with csv header encoding 'UTF8';
```

this command is ok

But I want to make file with ANSI encoding, because I want to open it in Microsoft Excel

```
COPY (select * from table) from '/tmp/123456.csv' with csv header encoding 'ANSI';
```

this command can't make csv file

Comment: There is no encoding "ANSI". If you mean a single-byte encoding, then you probably want `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: You mean `copy to`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be on Windows, maybe you want to use one of the [Windows encodings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED), for example `WIN1252` for western European languages.